# How to log duplicated frames using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to solve an issue.

I've recorder using an Atomos the Ultra HD 60p HDMI output from Chromecast with some Google Stadia Games.

Now I have some proRes file @60 fps, but the games are not of course at 60p. There are some frame drops for connection, and some frame variance according to the scene rendered.

I need to put on a chart the "real fps", so for every second I have to discard dubbed frames, remove from the "60 frame per seconds" the "dropped frames for second" and log the result in a time chart.

I know that using `mpdecimate` I can drop frames that do not differ greatly from the previous frame in order to reduce frame rate, and could be useful for me.

Do you know if there is something similar or a better way to do this?

Comment: If you only need to identify the dupes, see freezedetect filter.

Comment: @Gyan I want the FPS

Comment: There's no concept of a 'real' FPS. You identify the duplicated frames with their timings, and then calculate the number of non-dupes in each time interval of interest.